# AIME number theory problem (unique factorization domains)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, contest-math

I'd greatly appreciate some help with the following problem, from a mock AIME I took.

Compute the largest squarefree positive integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})\cap \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a unique factorization domain.

Comment: Is $\overline {\Bbb Z}$ the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Ratigan I thought $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ just referred to the extended line, similar to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that you can't have a unique factorization domain with infinity in it.  Also, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-n})\cap \overline{\Bbb Z}=\overline{\Bbb Z}$ under your definition.

Comment: Interesting.  Test author has a sense of humor, apparently.

Comment: Wait, why would you say so?

Comment: If this is preparation for the high school competition, the difficulty level looks like a serious overkill.  Unless it is to some extent a joke and a challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a joke as in "mock the AIME (by smarter-than-thou high school students who wrote the mock problem)", not a "mock test problem to prepare for the real test".

Explanation: it is a test of general knowledge more advanced than the level of the competition, including notation that is meant to be unfamiliar to many users of the mock test.

$\bar{Z}$ is the algebraic integers (algebraic numbers that are roots of a monic polynomial with $Q$ coefficients).

$Q(\sqrt{-n}) \cap \bar{Z}$ is the ring of integers in the quadratic field $Q(\sqrt{-n})$.

It is well known (but mentioned later in most people's mathematics education) that there are $10$ values of $n$ for which that ring has unique factorization, the largest being $163$.  The proof is a notoriously hard problem that was unsolved for about 150 years, after being stated as a conjecture by Gauss based on his rather extensive theory of quadratic forms.  It is not something that could possibly be solved during a competition.

The problem is a way for some students to signal others that they are more/equally precocious, depending on whether the others got the joke or not.

Comment: Yes, I do think the person who gave me the problem set had that sort of intention.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, you are asking for the largest squarefree integer $n$ such that  $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-n}]\cap\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ has class number $1$. It was conjectured by Gauss that $n=163$, but this was not proven until 1952, and it is now known as the [Stark-Heegner Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem).

Comment: Is there a more elementary approach? For me, the Stark-Heegner theorem is essentially equivalent to pulling a rabbit out of a hat.

Comment: @Ayesha: Not really. Famously, the Heegner proved the theorem in 1952, but the had some details missing, and was not accepted until 15 years later when Stark gave a complete proof. In 1969, Baker provided a different approach, proving a powerful theorem on linear combinations of logarithms of algebraic numbers which implies the Stark-Heegner theorem.